# OG image height and width are not applied to image, even though they appear in html

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, metadata, meta-tags

I have defined OG metadata, including images, for my Rails 7 website. I'm using the meta-tags gem to set the metadata.

When I use the Facebook debugger tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/), I see that the image is not rendered as a square (400 x 400), and when I test in WhatsApp, the image is not rendered at all (presumably because it's too large).

Even though the html is rendering the height and width, it seems like those dimensions are not being applied.

```
def set_social_meta_tags
    set_meta_tags title: t("layouts.header.parks"),
                  description: t("layouts.footer.tag_line"),
                  og: {
                    title: :title,
                    description: :description,
                    type: "website",
                    url: "https://example.com" + request.path,
                    image: { _: "https://example.jpeg", width: 400, height: 400}
                  },
                  twitter: {
                    card: "summary",
                    description: :description,
                    title: :title,
                    image: { _: "https://example.jpeg", width: 400, height: 400}
                  }
  end
```

The html renders like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://myasset.jpeg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="400">
```